# mean and covarince matrix of AR(1)

Tags: expected-value, covariance, conditional

assume I have a price data called pt, I fitted   AR(1) model

`p_t`= alpha + beta `pt_1` + `e_t` , where `e_t` i.i.d and follows a normal distribution  with (0,sigma^2 )

I applied on R  : Arima(data,order=c(1,0,0),method='ML')

I have :
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean

Coefficients:
ar1    mean
0.0707  0.0013
s.e.  0.0724  0.0008

sigma^2 = 0.000112:  log likelihood = 592.5
AIC=-1178.99   AICc=-1178.86   BIC=-1169.27

Training set error measures:
ME       RMSE         MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -1.323488e-06 0.01052662 0.007973123 97.40943 120.8574 0.7006081
ACF1
Training set 0.006295129

Now,
I want to calculate E(`p_t` | `p_t-1` ) , how can I do that in R ?
Also, How can I calculate my covariance matrix which defined as follow :

SIGMA_t = var( `p_t` | `p_t-1` )  ?

Thanks in advance